# iOS keyboard dismiss button for custom keyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, ios-app-extension

I am creating a custom keyboard extension for iOS 8. I am trying to implement the dismiss/hide keyboard button. I am using `UITextDocumentProxy` to edit the text and insert characters. How can I implement something like this:

```
[textView resignFirstResponder];
```

but for `self.textDocumentProxy`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document says: use [`- dismissKeyboard`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIInputViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIInputViewController/dismissKeyboard) method.

> Because a custom keyboard does not have access to the current text
>   input object, you cannot send it a resignFirstResponder message (as
>   you would to dismiss the system keyboard when you are developing an
>   app with text entry). To dismiss the custom keyboard, call
>   dismissKeyboard instead.